# updated all dependencies in ubuntu sever but my Laravel showing only folders and files in ubuntu server?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ubuntu-server

I have spend days to find out why can't my site is loading with real content. my laravel project is showing only folders and files but i have install it on my ubuntu server with all supported package. please help requried . my site results.musom.edu.np

Comment: Point your server root to the laravel `/public` directory. Ie in apache `DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public`

Comment: I have done that but still not loading please help me

Comment: site url: https://results.musom.edu.np/admin/login